# Document Library - Document ID as the URL for the document

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, document, url

In the document library I have document ID's set up for documents, when I browse a document the URL of the document has the documents name in it.

I want the document ID to be projected in the URL instead of the document name.

Is this possible?

Eg:- http://sharepointpocdev.server.region/documentcenter/ABC/Documents/TestDocument3.txt

the last part is the document name, i want the document ID to be projected there instead of the name.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: That is the fileurl.. if you try changing it ends up in 404 not found

Answer (score 1):

Yes you do so by using SharePoint designer workflow.
   Create a workflow on your DL(doc library) with following action

```
Set Name to Current Item:ID
```

were Name is filename field and Item:ID is your id of doc and start workflow on item added.
 If it resolves your query then please mark given solution as answer